# Symfony Form Component - change a field with addEventListener PRE_SUBMIT

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have custom Form Type:

```
class ChoosyType extends AbstractType
{

    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;


    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $parentForm = $form->getParent();
            $data = $event->getData();

            $newChoices = $this->createNewChoices($options['choices']);

            $parentForm->add($form->getName(), ChoosyType::class, array_replace($options, [
                'choices' => $newChoices,
                'data' => $this->entityManager->getRepository($options['class'])->find($data)
            ]));
        });
    }
```

When I submit my form - the change does not happen.
This is resulting only when I add the field to the parent form.
If I do not do this all works fine with the given choices.

Means when I add the new field - the value gets lost.

Did I something wrong or is this a know limitiation?

Comment: What is the purpose of this custom form type? Because you reference the same form type class inside the same class, `class ChoosyType { ... $parentForm->add($form->getName(), ChoosyType::class `

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by ``When I submit my form - the change does not happen.``. What "change" ? Did you try to add debug to see what data your 'choosy' field contain. Please provide more explanations, I think it'll really help to understand your problem

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just did not realized, that I can't remove the same field without triggering a infinite loop. I have some kind of custom logic for my choices and now I do it inside of the parent form. Thank you both for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved!

You just can not overwrite the same field from within the field itself on presubmit, sumbmit or aftersubmit.

It would result in an infinite loop.
Just do it inside of the parent, when you have to do some kind of custom logic.